# show tow desimals after MS SQL

Tags: casting, rounding, ms-query

Hi I have some problem which I can't solve, maybe some of you can help me 
I need to show result of division.

select 50/200
as we all know it supposed be 0.25, however, I got 0 
so them i try this

`SELECT ROUND(CAST(50  AS NUMERIC(18,2) )/ CAST(200 AS NUMERIC(18,2)),2)`

which gives me 0.25000000000000000000

I then tried to use `Round`

`select cast(round(50/200,2) as numeric(36,2))`

but its returning me 0.00

How would i fix this to just show 0.25?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
SELECT CAST ( ROUND ( 50 / 200.0 , 2 ) AS numeric ( 18 , 2 )) ;
```

EDIT:

Per your comment, you could modify it to this.

```
SELECT CAST ( ROUND ( @int1 / CAST ( @int2 AS numeric ( 18 , 2 )) , 2 ) AS numeric ( 18 , 2 )) ;
```

Comment: it works in this case, but  the problem in reall query it looks like SELECT CAST ( ROUND ( `column1 / column2`, 2 ) AS numeric ( 36 , 2 )) so i cant just simply add .0 to the end

Comment: You gave me a -1 because i answered your question, but did not answer your unlisted question?